# Module 'module' has no attribute 'celery'

Tags: python, django, celery

I need to use Celery at my project but i got some errors when i try to install at my project. I've read the [Celery's doc for Django](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html), but i've been taking the same error.

#### My tree project :

- **src**

  - __init__.py
  - celery.py
  - **core**

    - __init__.py
  - **project_auth**

    - __init__.py
    - serializer.py
    - tasks.py
  - settings.py
  - urls.py
  - wsgi.py
- texto.md

##### src/_*init*_.py :

```py
# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

##### src/celery.py :

```py
import os

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'src.settings')
app = Celery('src')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

##### src/settings.py :

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #Django apps :
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #Meus apps : 
    'src.core',
    'src.project_auth',
    'src.product',
    #Apps de terceiros :   
    'django_celery_results',
    'rest_framework',
    "rest_framework.authtoken",    
]

CELERY_CONFIG = {
    "CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER": "json",
    "CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT": ["json"],
    "CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER": "json",
    "CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND": None,
    "CELERY_TIMEZONE": "UTC",
    "CELERY_ENABLE_UTC": True,
    "CELERY_ENABLE_REMOTE_CONTROL": False,
}
```

#### docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  
  web:    
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    tty: true
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_app

  db:
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_db
    image: postgres:14
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  cache:
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_celery_broker
    image: rabbitmq:3.9
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
    
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

On docker bash i run  `celery --app src.project_auth` and got :

```sh
Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app': 
Unable to load celery application.
Module 'src.project_auth' has no attribute 'celery'
```

### Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your **celery.py** file is in the wrong location,  from the error message you should move **celery.py** into the **project_auth** folder.

```
Module 'src.project_auth' has no attribute 'celery'
```

This indicates Celery is expecting **src/project_auth/celery.py** whereas you have **src/celery.py**

The other option would be to change the bash script to

```
celery --app src
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you, that really help. But wen i ran the code ``` celery -A src worker -l INFO ```
I got this error ```
[2021-11-13 15:41:29,189: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 16.00 seconds... (8/100)
```

Comment: The problem here is Celery is looking for RabbitMQ on 127.0.0.1 (localhost),  however because you are using Docker Compose it is 3 different containers.   Docker Compose sets up the host resolution to the name of the container,  so in this case us using 'cache' as the hostname will work.  You need to set CELERY_BROKER_URL to amqp://user:pass@cache:5672  I am not sure what the default user/pass should be in RabbitMQ.